# Execute sql query by cron job

Tags: php, magento, cron

I need to reset all my documents number in my magento each. My hosting is limiting the use of event scheduler with my actual plan, so I'm asking if exist a way to execute a query on my db using a php file and a cron job executing each year at midnight. I think it needed also to store my db admin password. It is secure to create a php script with db password inside? Or there's another way to make that?

Comment: I'm wondering how magento is storing your DB password if not in a PHP file.

Comment: It seems like this would belong on the [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).